# making basis for a vector space from bases for subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is about adding elements of subsets of bases to get different bases.  Let's start with an example.

Suppose one has the vectors $v_{1,1},v_{1,2},v_{2,1},v_{2,2}$ as a basis for a space $V$ (over, say, the reals).  It might so happen that $v_{1,1},v_{1,2}$ and $v_{2,1},v_{2,2}$ are each bases for interesting subspaces, and one might want a new basis for $V$ which consists of sums of vectors from each, created in a systematic way.  However, just doing $$w_1=v_{1,1}+v_{2,1}, w_2=v_{1,1}+v_{2,2}, w_3=v_{1,2}+v_{2,1}, w_4=v_{1,2}+v_{2,2}$$ in a lexicographic fashion does *not* work, because e.g. $w_1+w_4=w_2+w_3$.

Now in general there might be $p$ subspaces each of which has $q$ vectors $v_{i,j}$ with $1\leq i\leq p$ and $1\leq j\leq q$.  Even though it might be nice if, of the $q^p$ possible combinations by just summing, at least $pq$ of them should be linearly independent, we see there are likely to be way too many relations for this to be true, since it fails even with $q=p=2$.

In the original example, though, switching $w_4=v_{1,2}-(v_{2,1}+v_{2,2})$ [does give a basis](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzzVbBVyE0sKcqs0IiONtQx0AHiWB0wC8gGskAiEDEQSxeEYmM1ebl89YoS87I1NAEcxQ_P&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) for $V$ (as do many other options involving minus signs), so this suggests the following.

> Question: In this situation, is there a always a basis of $V$ consisting of summed vectors, one from each subspace, where we can choose among $$v_{i,1},v_{i,2},\ldots ,v_{i,q},-\sum_{j=1}^q v_{i,j}$$ as the $q+1$ options for the $i$th subspace in the sum?

I presume that this is probably pretty "obvious" in some sense, but can't find a reference.  Ideally there would be a *systematic* way to produce such a basis (maybe using [exterior algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/528042/24113)?), but any reference will do for further sleuthing.  Unfortunately the word "subbasis" has a rather different meaning in mathematics than this situation, so an internet search has proved hopeless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such a basis always exists.  Let me prove something a bit more general.

**Theorem:**  Let $V_1,\dots,V_p$ be vector spaces over a field $k$ and for each $i$ let $S_i\subseteq V_i$ be a nonempty subset which spans $V_i$.  Suppose moreover that for each $i>1$, there is a linear relation $\sum c_js_j=0$ between elements $s_j\in S_i$ such that $\sum c_j\neq 0$.  Then there exists a basis for the direct sum $V=\bigoplus V_i$, each element of which is a sum of elements from each $S_i$.

(To apply this to your question, take $S_i=\{v_{i,1},\dots,v_{i,q},-\sum_j v_{i,j}\}$ which satisfies a linear relation in which all the coefficients are $1$.)

*Proof*: Using induction on $p$, it suffices to prove the result in the case $p=2$.  (The cases $p\leq 1$ are trivial, and given the result for $p=2$, the induction step then follows by applying the $p=2$ result to $V_1'=\bigoplus_{i<p}V_i$ and $V_2'=V_p$, letting $S_1'$ be the basis for $V_1'$ given by the induction hypothesis and $S_2'=S_p.$)

So let us suppose $p=2$; we must show the set $S$ of elements of the form $x+y$ for $x\in S_1$ and $y\in S_2$ spans $V$.   By hypothesis, we have a relation $\sum c_js_j=0$ for elements $s_j\in S_2$ with $\sum c_j\neq 0$.  Fix any element $x\in S_1$ and consider the elements $x+s_j\in S$.  The linear combination $\sum c_j(x+s_j)$ of these elements is equal to $\sum c_j x$ which is a nonzero multiple of $x$.  Thus $x$ is in the span of $S$.  But now also we see that any $y\in S_2$ is in the span of $S$, since we can write $y=(x+y)-x$ and $x+y\in S$.  Thus the span of $S$ contains both $S_1$ and $S_2$, and thus is all of $V$.

Comment: Thanks - somehow I was making it too difficult for myself by not thinking of induction even though I had already essentially done $p=2$ - sigh.

Comment: Separately, I presume this isn't a "named" theorem anywhere, so I guess I will cite this ("simple induction argument, see e.g. math.sx.com/... thanks to EW") in an upcoming preprint.